# fix module.js:328 throw err;

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm learning nodejs through some tutorials and so far it went smooth. Now I got an error and I'm stuck. Can anyone help me with it.

This is my app.js file

```
var greet5 = require('/greet5');
greet5.greet();
```

And this is my greet5.js file which is located in same directory as app.js

```
var greeting = "Hello from Revieling Module pattern";

function greet(){
    console.log(greeting);
}

module.exports = {
    greet : greet
}
```

when I run node app.js on terminal this is the error I'm facing.

```
 module.js:328
        throw err;
        ^

Error: Cannot find module '/greet5'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pankaja/Nodejs/Tests/23-Module Patterns/app.js:19:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `./` that indicates "from the current directory" in your require: `require('/greet5')`. Voting to close as a typo. For reference: [nodejs module search algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

Comment: Oh. Thanks alot. Didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

The README.md file of the nodejs project, appeared after running `nodejs install`, explains you how to run the web app through nodejs.

It says you have to execute `npm run dev` on the command line.

Here you are the default README.md:

````
# Front End Boilerplate
Front-end boilerplate for creating new web projects with Gulp.js and everything you need to get started.
# Getting Started
Required! Gulp installed `npm install -g gulp`
```
$ cd html-boilerplate
$ npm install
$ npm run dev  
```
# Build to production
```
$ npm run build
```
Thank you for your suggestions!
````